# Application that uses own queues as holders of long-term process operations

Tags: nservicebus, long-running-processes

I want to make a long-term process handler and use for it NServiceBus.
The role of NServiceBus is to hold an operations of that process (some kind of batch process)
The problem is that I have more than one type of long-term processes and each of them must run parallel, so pushing all messages in one queue is not that I have to do, I think.

Logic is:
1) Receive an order of a long-term process,
2) Divide it into N operations,
3) Each operation "pack" into the message and push in the queue,
4) According to the type of message, particular handler will handle messages and do the operation it holds.

I can't put all of the operations in one queue because my application should handle another messages, that requires fast response. If queue would be full of operations, another messages would wait a lot of time to be processed

So, does anyone know how to solve that problem ?

Comment: Have you seen sagas? They are designed for long-running processes.

Comment: In addition to Sagas, it sounds like you need to draw some boundaries around the operations and consider creating separate endpoints for them.  Coordination between them can be handled via Sagas.

Comment: @UdiDahan, my long-running process divides into 2+ billions operations, which may partially fail (e.g. ++++--++-++---++-). And I need to restart failed (which thrown an exceptions) operations. And queues (not sagas) is the best solution here, I think.

Comment: Then I think you need to look at a more domain-specific design rather than generically leaning on either queues or sagas. These are the boundaries that Adam Fyles was talking about in his comment.

Comment: @AdamFyles all operations are the same.
For example, someone asked my application to run long-therm process. He sent "OperationId" (for notification when it completed) and collection of some IDs and. Each IDs is a basis of operation. Then I divide all process to N operations like "DoOperation(1,1)", "DoOperation(2,1)", "DoOperation(3,1)". Each operation has the same logic, only Id is different. But some of operations may fail due to some technical exceptions. And I need to repeat them if failed.I already made a such service without NServiceBus or something.But I want to use all power of queues

Comment: You may want to checkout putting those operations into a pipeline using ISpecifyMessageOrderHandling interface.  Then you may be into the Distributor(master/workers) to load balance it all.

Answer (score 0):

You should properly set the number of worker threads in the access queue config settings of the long-running process endpoint.

if you are using `MSMQ` check out [this](http://www.nservicebus.com/faq/MsmqTransportConfig.aspx) and especially the tag `<MsmqTransportConfig ErrorQueue="error" NumberOfWorkerThreads="1" MaxRetries="5"/>`

Every idle worker thread pull out a message from the queue although another thread is still processing another message. In this way you shoud achieve the parallel computation requirement you described in your scenario.

Comment: If I will put all messages in one queue, there may be billions of messages of different types (handling all of them can take 1-2 days), while some types requires immediate handling. So, I need more than one queue...

Comment: I think you are looking for a load balancer as the NServiceBus distributor(http://nservicebus.com/DistributorV3.aspx)